# Close and comment with link questions about rep recalc on SO instead of migrating them

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

For just this brief time during the recalc, can we agree to close as "off topic" on SO with a comment link to the recalc blog post instead of migrating to meta where we simply have to go through the exercise again?

Answer (score 7):

I feel bad for a lot of these people. First, some of them put time into researching what happened. Some even write detailed posts explaining what they did to troubleshoot the problem. Then they get barked at for asking the question, and downvoted (reducing their rep even more).

## FOR THE LOVE OF ALL THINGS HOLY SOMEONE PLEASE PUT A BANNER UP ON SO!!!

Comment: It will pass...

Comment: I get @Jeff's point that he doesn't want to hear from the thousands of people who won't know or care unless they see the banner, but I think it would be better to take the full hit all at once and put the banner up on SO as well rather than drag this thing out.

Comment: And where are all the kids from SF and SU? Did they get some message SO didn't?

Comment: @random I would guess it has been less of an issue on SF and SU because, at least on SF, the users seem to be grouped in either the higher level users who answer alot and are invested in the site and read the blog and meta etc, and the users who come to get answers but don't care about their rep (especially on SU), there are less of the in between users who are collecting rep, but are not aware of the blog, and the other sites in the trilogy. It could very well be that the SF users who were confused came straight to Meta. Also there are the fact there are less users.

Comment: I don't feel bad for them. In fact I've been flagging a lot of these posts as offensive or spam (and anyone who dares post an answer, too). If someone is aware enough of their reputation value on SO to notice that it has gone down overnight, they should be aware of meta or be able to find themselves to the FAQ (which contains a link to meta).

Answer (score 3):

Makes sense.

I don't see the point of burning up close votes on two sites for the same questions.