# Let's not migrate unicorn questions to meta

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, unicorns, april-fools

[Just like with rep recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43497/close-and-comment-with-link-questions-about-rep-recalc-on-so-instead-of-migrating), I think things will work out better if these questions are edited on the original site to link to the blog post and then simply closed (and later deleted).

Comment: What, is Meta getting *too* sparkly for your tastes? :-)

Comment: What I want to know is who has to do all the mucking out of the stables when the unicorns have bolted this year?  Looks like a job for the moderators to me.

Comment: @Anthony: Don't be silly: everyone knows that unicorns poop gemstones, and cleaning the stables is done by the jewellers.

Answer (score 8):

How intolerant! Next you're gonna say that we should build a giant fence around Meta to keep them out. Contrary to what people like you may say, unicorns *are not* stealing views from other Meta questions. They are merely taking the views that other questions wouldn't want to have in the first place.

When will the xenophobia end? Unicorns have just as much right to become Meta citizens as you or I. Don't forget that *we* were once immigrants from SO too.

Comment: ...too much free time. :-P

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a good plan.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree; it is not right for people to be gaining reputation for flamboyant unicorn posts on SO, but it is ABSOLUTELY IMPERATIVE on meta.

Comment: No, what's great is that they'll have all that inflated rep and when it gets deleted quietly, they'll be in for a shock on the recalc.

Answer (score 0):

That didn't happen in the recalc, did it?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43497/close-and-comment-with-link-questions-about-rep-recalc-on-so-instead-of-migrating

Comment: He means that, with the recalc, he also _thought_ that things would work out better this way.

Comment: I think the mods were doing that in the background, but the 3k closers were still migrating.

Comment: @daniel, exactly what I meant

Answer (score 0):

So what .. its only +5 per unicorn upvote anyway, after the recalc. What could go wrong?

Comment: But still +10 for answers.